# Redirection from jsp:include page

Tags: jsp, redirect, jstl, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I want the user to be redirected to Login.jsp if the "role" stored in Session Scope doesn't match with the Request Parameter "accessRole"

HomePage.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp">
<jsp:param value="d" name="accessRole" />
</jsp:include>
```

Header.jsp

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.role!=param.accessRole}">
<c:redirect url="Login.jsp"/> 
</c:if>
```

The above code does not perform the redirection as expected.

I tried using ExternalContext's redirect() and jsp:forward in place of <c:redirect>, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect inside a JSP include, it's often already too late. If you have read the appserver logs, you should have seen an `IllegalStateException: response already committed` (just because the content of the parent page is already been sent to the response).

The real solution for this is to implement a `Filter` which is mapped on the `url-pattern` covering the parent page.

Comment: This does make me wonder. The `<c:redirect>` was provided for a reason, and yet it seems extremely limited to me.

Comment: You may have luck with it inside the first 2KB of the response (i.e. at top of parent JSP page). But indeed, it is somewhat superfluous, I have also never used it.

Comment: I'm using JSF, and not JSP.
Is there a tutorial on how to use filters with JSF..?

Comment: JSF runs on top of JSP/Servlet, you can perfectly use Filters. Say, you are even using non-JSF tags in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

JSP includes are not *allowed* to send a redirect. You'll have to use:

```
<jsp:include.directive file="url"/>
```